# Visual Studio 2017 RC installation failure "product ... cannot be found"

Tags: visual-studio

I am trying to install Visual Studio Professional 2017 RC on Windows 10 but the installer reports:

```
A product matching the following parameters cannot be found:

channelId: VisualStudio.15.Release
productId: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.Professional
```

Is this fixable?

Comment: Did you have a previous Visual Studio Installation? If yes, did you uninstall it before installing VS 17 RC? Because if not, you should!

Comment: I have Visual Studio 2015 Prof installed. Can't that coexist with 2017 RC?

Comment: It may cause various problems (although it of course should not, but there are a few bugs)

Comment: I have 2013 and 2015 co-exist without issues. When i try to install 2017, facing the reported channelid issue. Tried installcleanup, removing intaller folder etc didnt work. Now trying to remove 2015 as no other option

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I previously installed VS 15 Release and removed it. I had the same issue and fixed it by removing installer folder from here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\ *Installer*

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue and the following has helped me. A clean-up and removal of vs and installation folder was not enough in my case.

Here are the steps I've taken:

- uninstalled Visual Studio (and other Visual Studio installations)
- run C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\InstallCleanup.exe -full"
- removed all the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio" folders
- removed "C:\Program Data\Microsoft\Visual Studio\ folder
- restarted system

In the end I think removing of Program Data location did the final trick. I had to run a repair after the successful installation to make VS Extensions work.

Answer (score 4):

Please follow the cleanup steps and retry your VS install

See if you have this file on your machine: "%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\InstallCleanup.exe"
If so, please launch it from an admin command prompt with a -full param:
InstallCleanup.exe -full

If not, please manually delete the "%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer” folder
Relaunch the newly downloaded vs_enterprise.exe (or vs_professional.exe or vs_community.exe…)
Allow the first step to install the installer
Once the installer comes up and you can see workload choices (.net desktop and the like), close it
Go launch the same InstallCleanup.exe to clean up old build of VS
Then relaunch vs_enterprise.exe and install VS.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that I had was because I had a Visual Studio 2017 layout and I wanted to make a Visual Studio 2019 layout in the same directory.

If you are creating a **new** offline installation layout on top of an **old** offline installation layout, you need to delete every **file** inside the layout folder (And only the layout folder not sub-directories).
This way the new (channel) information will be replaced and installation goes without errors.